# Dependencies work fine in maven but not in sbt

Tags: maven, sbt

In my scala project I have a dependency that works fine in my `maven` project, but throws an error in my `sbt` project.

In this specific case the dependency in my `build.sbt` is:
`"com.sksamuel.elastic4s" % "elastic4s-xpack-security_2.11" % "5.1.5"`

while in my `pom.xml`:

```
[...]
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
        <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
        <spark.version>2.1.0</spark.version>
    </properties>
[...]
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>elastic4s-xpack-security_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
[...]
```

and the error shown is:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.elasticsearch.client#x-pack-transport;5.1.1: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.elasticsearch.client#x-pack-transport;5.1.1: not found
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Mar 1, 2017 4:40:59 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="/Users/salvob/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2016.3/sbt.last.log">/Users/salvob/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2016.3/sbt.last.log</a>
```

in fact the [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/x-pack-transport/5.2.0) doesn't exist.

But my question here is: Why in maven this issue doesn't show up? What does happen in maven that it doesn't in SBT ?

Comment: Probably because maven is building the project, not running it. Could you show your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to build.sbt:

```
resolvers in ThisBuild += "elastic" at "https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven"
```

See [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/java-clients.html) for gradle:

```
// Add the Elasticsearch Maven Repository
  maven {
    url "https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven"
  }
```